# Converting Dictionary to Sorted List of Tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, sortedlist

So I am trying to convert a dictionary into a sorted list containing tuples. I have been able to convert the dictionary to a sorted list no problem. My issue is creating a tuple out of the key AND corresponding values, then passing that into a sorted list.

I have tried just turning the dictionary into a sorted list (which technically works but the tuple seems to be a separate entity in the list).

Then I tried to pull the key and the all the values apart and stitch them back together with a for statement but I've spent enough time on this now that I'm just blocked up and can't see why it won't pass through.

Below are the two functions I have tried to create:

```
#function #1
def sort_contacts(diction):    
    my_key_list = list(diction.keys())
    my_val_list = list(diction.values())
    for x in range(0,len(my_key_list)):
        for k in my_key_list:
            for x,v in my_val_list:
                new_val=(k, x, v)
            new_list=[new_val]
    return(new_list)

#function #2
def sort_contacts(diction):
    sorta = [(k,v) for k,v in diction.items()]
    sorta = list(sorta)
    sorta.sorta
    #sortc = sortb.split()
    return sorta
```

For function #1, Test Failed.
Expected:

```
[('Freud, Anna', '1-541-754-3010', 'anna@psychoanalysis.com'), ('Horney, Karen', '1-541-656-3010', 'karen@psychoanalysis.com'), ('Welles, Orson', '1-312-720-8888', 'orson@notlive.com')]
```

but got:

```
[('Freud, Anna', '1-541-754-3010', 'anna@psychoanalysis.com')]
```

For function #2, Test Failed.
Expected:

```
[('Freud, Anna', '1-541-754-3010', 'anna@psychoanalysis.com'), ('Horney, Karen', '1-541-656-3010', 'karen@psychoanalysis.com'), ('Welles, Orson', '1-312-720-8888', 'orson@notlive.com')]
```

but got:

```
[('Freud, Anna', ('1-541-754-3010', 'anna@psychoanalysis.com')), ('Horney, Karen', ('1-541-656-3010', 'karen@psychoanalysis.com')), ('Welles, Orson', ('1-312-720-8888', 'orson@notlive.com'))]
```

Comment: Please post the original dictionary

Comment: Okay, so the second function gives much better results (although I'm not sure what `sorta.sorta` is supposed to do; should it be `sorta.sort()`?). Now you need to convert `['string', ('some', 'tuple')]` to `['string', 'some', 'tuple']`. Can you do that?

Comment: As @ForceBru pointed out, `sorta.sort` doesn't work because it doesn't call the sort function. You need to use `sorta.sort()` to sort the list. When you use `sorta.sort` it just returns the built-in class `<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>` thus doesn't do anything to the list. It is a function and it must be called following the proper function call syntax:  **function name followed by parenthesis**

Comment: 1) `sorta = list(sorta)` is redundant, because it's already a list. 2) `sorta = list(diction.items())` is sufficient; the list comprehension is unnecessary.

Comment: On the first function, `new_list=[new_val]` this overwrites previous values.  Perhaps with `new_list.append(new_val)` it would work better.  On the second function, I presume your dictionary has a tuple, i.e:`"name": ("some", "truple", "tuple")`.  So the second function is doing what is told.  You have to take those strings out of the tuple.

Comment: You could try something like `sorta = sorted((k, *v) for k, v in diction.items())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like:

```
def sort_contacts(diction):
    sorta = [(k, v[0], v[1]) for k,v in diction.items()]
    # sort it somehow? 
    return sorta
```

Answer (score 0):

@Akaisteph7 thank you that answer worked. I sorted it by sorta.sort() and then everything passed through correctly.

here is the final code:

```
def sort_contacts(diction):
    sorta = [(k, v[0], v[1]) for k,v in diction.items()]
    sorta.sort() 
    return sorta
```

Thanks everybody!